# Running Multiple Logstash Configuration in One Logstash Instance

Tags: logstash

I would like to ask,
how to run multiple logstash configuration in one logstash instance, I mean running the below queries same time.

```
./logstash -f first.conf
./logstash -f second.conf
./logstash -f third.conf
....
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that simply specify various pipelines in the `config/pipelines.yml` file like the following:

```
- pipeline.id: my_first_pipeline
  path.config: "/path_to_first_pipeline.conf"
- pipeline.id: my_second_pipeline
  path.config: "/path_to_second_pipeline.conf"
```

Then run logstash without any additional option (like `bin/logstash` from the logstash directory). It'll run all the pipelines specified in the `pipelines.yml` file.

Obviously, you can add specific options for each individual pipeline in the `pipelines.yml` file (e.g. number of workers, batch_size, and others).

Comment: what about pipeline workers option and queue type? Thanks your answer

Comment: What do u mean? There is the doc-ref: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/multiple-pipelines.html#multiple-pipelines

Comment: if my different pipelines have different output and filters, will it consider these individually?... I read in other places that it will not.

Comment: I'd recommends you to check distributor patterns which ables to manages these individually https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#distributor-pattern

Comment: You made a good answer, if you liked the question feel free to upvote :)